# How to align <div> vertically in the middle of another <div>?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on an assignment to create a shopping cart, and I'm trying to align my item total vertically in the middle of the other  it is nested in.

Here is my code:

```css
.itemInfo {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.itemTotal {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h3>Items</h3>
  <div class="cart">
    <div class="itemInfo">
      <img class="itemImg" src="someimg.png">
      <p class="itemNumber">#Item-S017-01</p>
      <h4>Item Name</h4>
      <p><input type="number" class="qty" placeholder="1" min="0"> x $250.00</p>
    </div>

    <div class="itemTotal">
      <p><span>$250.00</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve - where "$15.00" is aligned:[image]

I had just started learning HTML a few days ago and I'm not really good at it. Appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on the `.cart` element.

You're not quite using `display: table-cell` correctly on the `.itemTotal` and we can remove the need for that by using flex.

```css
.itemInfo {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.cart {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```